# What is the meaning of " these two anchors have been lowered"?

Tags: vocabulary

> The choice of a truth-value as the Meaning (semantic value) of a complete sentence was made inevitable by the a, b, c( that's my rewrite and omit)...Once ***these two anchors***-the assignment oftruth-values to sentences, and the assignment ofobjects to singular terms-**have been lowered**, the kind of entity that constitutes the semantic value of an expression of any of the various other kinds is more or less determined by its grammatical category.

My question is what is the meaning of "anchors be lowered", I have searched it but didn't found the answer. Thank you very much.
It is from a book:Evans, G. 1982: The Varieties of Reference. Oxford: Oxford University Press.
[image]

Comment: Ask yourself - for what reason does a ship lower an anchor?

Comment: Thank you for providing a proper attribution of the source of the example. However, you gave it as a scanned image of the text. Please do not include images of text. They hinder searchability and accessibility. See https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/91457 and https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5364/screenshots-in-questions-what-should-we-do-to-discourage-such-behavior/5365#5365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally, an anchor is a heavy object lowered from a ship to tether it and keep it in place. Metaphorically, 'anchor' is used in different ways (as a verb and a noun) to mean something that maintains stability.

In your example, it seems like the 'anchors' are two founding principles on which a greater body of work is built.